# deep learning early stopping callback strange behavior in a loop

Tags: keras, deep-learning, callback, tensorflow2.0, early-stopping

I'm testing sequential models accuracy in a loop including an early stopping callback.

My environment is

```
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py37h6c5654b_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I'm running my tests in a jupyter notebook.

Python version is 3.7.7

```
for x in range:
   create_model()
   history=model.fit(..callback=[es_val_loss]..)
```

my callback is

```
es_val_loss = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                   mode='auto', 
                   verbose=0, 
                   patience=PATIENCE,
                   min_delta=ES_VAL_LOSS_MIN_DELTA,
                   baseline=None,
                   restore_best_weights=True)
```

and my create_model() is

```
def create_model( ... ):
    ## Create our model
    model = Sequential()

    # 1st layer
    model.add(Dense())
    model.add(Dropout())
    # other layers
    model.add(Dense())
    model.add(Dropout())

    model.add(Dense())
    model.add(Dropout())

    # output layer: dim=1, activation sigmoid
    model.add(Dense( ))
    myoptimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',   # since we are predicting 0/1
             optimizer=myoptimizer,
             metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

With the first model, the callback response starts from inf for val_loss

```
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to ... saving model to ...
```

For the other models in the loop, my callback retains the result of the previous model and doesn't start from inf but with the previous model best minimal val_loss value.

```
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from ... to ..., saving model to ...
```

how can I solve this behavior so that each model iteration starts with its own cleared values for the callback?

I tried with setting `model.reset_states()`and/or `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` in the loop without success.

**Edit**

After further investigations, I found that the messages sent by the callback are misleading.
If I put `verbose=0` in the callback arguments and `verbose=2` in the `**model.fit**` arguments, I can see that the callback is working as expected.

Comment: What about changing the first line in your loop with `model=create_model()`?

Comment: After further investigations, I found that the messages sent by the callback are misleading. If I put verbose=0 in the callback arguments and verbose=2 in the **model.fit** arguments, I can see that the callback is working as expected.

Comment: Cool, I suggest you add this as an answer, so that it may be useful for others in the future, too; otherwise you may simply prefer to delete the question.

Comment: I was having the same issue. Your post and answer were helpful. They solved my problem. Please add your solution as a n answer.